# Configuring quartz.net scheduler in .net

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I have an application in .Net framework and  I'm using quartz scheduler. I need to configure quartz. 
Now I have one method which is fired every 15 minutes. These method is used to do some work with database. I want, in case, that work of procedure is complete, then start waiting period and after that period again start these database method. 
For procedure there will be maximum time which cannot be longer. For examplpe 60 minutes. Do you have any ideas how to configure length of working procedure, how to stop when work is finished and how to define waiting time between?

Answer (score 0):

```
// configure Quartz
var stdSchedulerProperties = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "10" },
    { "quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold", "60000" }
};
var stdSchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(stdSchedulerProperties);
var scheduler = stdSchedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
scheduler.Start();

// create job and specify timeout
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<JobWithTimeout>()
    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .UsingJobData("timeoutInMinutes", 60)
    .Build();

// create trigger and specify repeat interval
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(15).RepeatForever())            
    .Build();

// schedule job 
scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger).Wait();

/// <summary>
///     Implementation of IJob. Represents the wrapper job for a task with timeout
/// </summary>
public class JobWithTimeout : IJob
{
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => Execute(context));
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(DoWork);
        workerThread.Start();

        context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.TryGetValue("timeoutInMinutes", out object timeoutInMinutes);
        TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((int)timeoutInMinutes);
        bool finished = workerThread.Join(timeout);
        if (!finished) workerThread.Abort();
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```